# What does ~(uint32_t) mean?

Tags: c, syntax

I'm reading a bit of C code in an OS kernel that says

```
x & ~(uint32_t)CST_IEc;
```

What does the `~()` mean? It's a tilde followed by parentheses!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`~()` is actually two things:

1. `(uint32_t)` is a cast.
2. `~` is a bitwise complement operator.

Answer (score 10):

A few more parantheses to clearify evaluation order:

```
(x & (~((uint32_t)CST_IEc)))
```

First `CST_IEc` is casted into a `uint32_t` then it is bitwise negated with `~` before being bitwise anded with `x` through `&`.

Answer (score 4):

You are interpreting the operator precedence incorrectly. The cast `(uint32_t)CST_IEc` is done first and `~` happens after that. Take a look at an operator precedence chart for help.

Answer (score 4):

- The `(uint32_t)` bit is a cast to a type of unsigned int (32 bits),
- the `~` means bitwise not (or complement), so it reverses the bits in `CST_IEc` after it has been cast to `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(uint32_t)CST_IEc; //casting CST_IEc to uint32_t

~( ) //taking one's complement
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the expression slightly differently:

```
(uint32_t)CST_IEc
```

This converts the value `CST_IEc` into a 32-bit unsigned integer.

```
~(uint32_t)CST_IEc;
```

The `~` then does a bit-wise inversion of the value; each one bit becomes a zero and each zero bit becomes a one.

The whole expression then does:

```
x & ~(uint32_t)CST_IEc;
```

This means that the result contains the bits in `x` except for the bits implied by the value of `CST_IEc`; those are zeroed.

So, if `CST_IEc` was, for sake of example, 0x0F00, and the input value of `x` was 0x12345678, the result would be 0x12345078.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't (uint32_t) a type cast?

~ is bitwise NOT